# Format characters não precisam de ser especificadas?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As format characters tem que ser especificadas? como por exemplo:

```
x = "Get rekt m8"
print "Eu disse: %r." % x
```

Então porque é que eu não precisei de especificar esta e funcionou á mesma?

```
hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %r"
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `esta funcionou`? Pode descrever qual comportamento você está observando diferente do que esperava?

Answer (score 0):

Uma string pode ser formatada a qualquer momento. O caractere *%* realiza a operação de formatação somente quando é utilizado como um operador. Enquanto isto não ocorre, a string em questão pode ser manipulada e utilizada sem nenhum problema.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Desde o Python 2.6, há uma forma mais poderosa para formatar strings:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting